# How to display large images + overlay with DirectX (or DirectShow?)

Tags: directx

I have an application (hardware) that produces large images (e.g. 2048x5000) very fast (e.g. 30 fps).
So I would like to use the GPU in order to scale and display them together with an overlay (e.g. text annotations).

What is the fastest way to do this?

- Copy images into an offscreen
  surface, stretch it into the
  backbuffer, redraw all annotations.
- Create textures (tiling?) and map them onto a rectangle
- DirectShow?
- Other options?

Thanks,
Florian

P.S.: Should run with Windows XP, too

Answer (score 0):

If it has to run in windows XP, your best bet is Direc3D 9, using a video card that supports up to 8192-height textures.  Otherwise, you will have to map 2-4 quads vertically to cover the whole area.

Surfaces and textures of the same format should be about the same speed, but StretchRect() with surfaces is going to be way more convenient.